# How to get a dataset from from_tensor_slices at any position (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I need to get the data at any position from the dataset.

It looks like:

```
tf.Tensor([77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
```

But the `.batch()` function can not give a random position:

```
a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.arange(100))
b = a.batch(10).shuffle(100).repeat()

for c in b.take(12):
    print(c)

tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
```

How can I get the data at any position?

Comment: Try `b = a.shuffle(100).batch(10).repeat()`.

Comment: it's not work.  `tf.Tensor([39 74 28 37 11 38 75 44 76 96], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([48 46  6 21 18 89 90 32 65 69], shape=(10,), dtype=int32)`

Comment: What do you mean is that every data starts at random, but the subsequent data is continuous?

Comment: Yes. but I have found that's not important for LSTM

Comment: You need `b = a.window(10, shift=1, drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(10)).shuffle(100)`.

Comment: its a ideal answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

To start the data at random but the subsequent data is continuous

```
a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.arange(100))
b = a.window(10, shift=1, drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(10)).shuffle(100)

for c in b.take(12):
    print(c)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
```

To start the data at random and but the subsequent data is not continuous

```
a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.arange(100))
b = a.shuffle(100).batch(10).repeat()

for c in b.take(12):
    print(c)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([ 2 65 77 48 39 62 88 92 98 10], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([75 13 21 26 87 86  3 71 45 57], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([ 4 90 43 58 93 31 17  9 72 42], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([36 37 83 19 11 99 52 89 56 82], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([22 94 68 60 12 74 73 61 29 84], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([40 69 64 70 32  8 54 80 15 67], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([55  7 47 51 28 18 27 30 95  5], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([50 63 81 85 97 59 20 24 14 25], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([66 78 79 23 38 76 46 44  6 35], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([34 41  1  0 49 53 96 16 91 33], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([33 51 41  5 27 49 34 32 22 68], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([65 28 85  7 42 39 91 57  1 72], shape=(10,), dtype=int64)
```